# Who is auth server in OAuth2.0 between two Apps eg. between Google and Twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, authorization

I know that **OAuth2.0** is framework using to authorization data request between apps, but to give this access auth server is required. It is my question: who is this server? Let's say: We have two apps: Twitter and Google. I am trying to register Twitter account using Google account. **And now where is this auth server?** Is it Google? Or maybe it is another third server (managed by Twitter and Google together where user data is?) If it is Google, how Twitter is able to check if user token (generated by auth server [Google??]) is valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first question,

> I am trying to register Twitter account using Google account. And now
> where is this auth server? Is it Google?

Yes, it's Google. If you're trying to login/register to Twitter via Google, Google is the authorization server. Because, Google has to authorize/delegate access to Twitter to access your data such as your Gmail id, username, etc.

Once you click on "Sign up with Google" button on the Twitter registration page, you will be redirected to the Google login page first (to see if you're an authenticated google user) and then Google would show you a consent page saying that "Twitter is trying to read your profile data, are you okay with this?". Once you click on "Allow" button, Google will generate an access_token, id_token, and refresh_token and pass it to Twitter.

On your second question,

> If it is Google, how Twitter is able to check if user token (generated
> by auth server [Google??]) is valid?

Twitter is not going to validate the tokens. Twitter can pass the token to retrieve your Google profile information from Google's **Resource Server** (where all your data reside)

Google's Resource Server is the one that's going to validate the token. It first checks the 'iss' claim of the token to see if the token is issued by Google's Authorization Server. Additionally, it would check for 'aud' to see if the token is issued for them (recipient of the token). Finally, it checks for the 'scope' claim to see if Twitter has the right access to request the data. For eg, they would need to request only read-only access to your profile, but not write access. There could be additional validation depending on the use case.

I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks! It make sense :D. So google's servers auth and resource have to know secret key of each other? Or maybe they communicate each other like: resource server get request from Twitter with token, so generating request to auth server with this token to ask it's validity and depending on the response it know if is it valid or not and if return asked resources or not?

Comment: Usually, in the OAuth2.0 spec, there will be an endpoint issued by Authorization Server called the 'Introspection endpoint'. When Twitter is trying to request a resource from Resource Server, the Resource Server can introspect the token using the Introspection endpoint. If the token is valid, the endpoint responds with the token's claim. With the claims, the resource server can have any validation, like scope verification.

PS: If it answers your question, kindly accept it as an answer so that it might help others who are referring to this question. Thanks